# Why is my Seed() method not saving and connecting entities correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a registration site for a conference for my organization, with multiple VIPs and guest speakers. The requirement is to track many details about each attendee including their arrival and departure plans and their local lodging information. In order to facilitate discussion with stakeholders on the types of reports we need to build, I want to populate my dev database with a batch of records from a CSV containing randomly generated information like name, arrival/departure date/time, etc. This will allow us to look at a working site without having to register and re-register many times.

However, I simply *cannot* get the Seed method to persist the relevant records properly, yet my controller which handles the registration works perfectly.

My database structure is basically an Attendee entity with child entities for `TravelSchedule`, `LodgingArrangement`, and various lookups. Here are excerpts from my entities:

```
public class Attendee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ... other strings/etc ...

    public virtual TravelSchedule TravelSchedule { get; set; }
    public int TravelScheduleId { get; set; }

    public virtual LodgingArrangment LodgingArrangement { get; set; }
    public int LodgingArrangementId { get; set; }
}

public class TravelSchedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ... other properties ...

    public virtual Attendee Attendee { get; set; }
    public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
}

public class LodgingArrangement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ... other properties ...

    public virtual Attendee Attendee { get; set; }
    public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the content of my context's `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Attendee>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.TravelSchedule)
    .WithRequired(r => r.Attendee);

modelBuilder.Entity<TravelSchedule>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.ArrivalMode)
            .WithMany(m => m.Arrivals)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.ArrivalModeId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<TravelSchedule>()
            .HasRequired(m => m.DepartureMode)
            .WithMany(m => m.Departures)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.DepartureModeId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Attendee>()
            .HasOptional(a => a.LodgingArrangement)
            .WithRequired(l => l.Attendee);
```

The following is an excerpt from my Seed method.

```
var attendees = GetAttendeesFromCsv();

context.Attendees.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Email, attendees.ToArray());
context.SaveChanges();

var dbAttendees = context.Attendees.ToList();

foreach (var attendee in dbAttendees)
{
        attendee.TravelSchedule = CreateTravelSchedule();
        context.Entry<Attendee>(attendee).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

`GetAttendeesFromCsv()` extracts the records from the CSV into Attendee objects, thanks to the CsvHelper package. CreateTravelSchedule creates a new TravelSchedule entity and populates it with data from lookup tables using the `SelectRandom()` method from extensionmethod.com. The bottom line is that I extract the CSV rows into Attendee objects, add a new randomly-generated TravelSchedule entity, and save the resulting Attendee with attached TravelSchedule.

*Except this does not work.* Instead the above code adds the TravelSchedule records to the database, but the AttendeeId is always set to 0 in the table. Also the Attendees table is populated with all of the records from the CSV, but the TravelScheduleId on each row is always 0 as well. However, when stepping through the `update-database` call with the debugger the attendee.Id is populated properly, so by my understanding EF should pick up that the two are related and persist the *related* TravelSchedule at the same time as the Attendee. So why isn't EF connecting the two records?

Changing the loop to this:

```
foreach (var attendee in dbAttendees)
{
    var travel = CreateTravelSchedule();
    travel.AttendeeId = attendee.Id;  // I also tried just travel.Attendee = attendee, without success
    context.TravelSchedules.Add(travel);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Results in this error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.TravelSchedules_dbo.Attendees_Id". The conflict occurred in database "MySite.DAL.MyContext", table "dbo.Attendees", column 'Id'.
```

So it appears I cannot add the TravelSchedule entity to the Attendee, *and* I also cannot go "backwards" by creating the TravelSchedule and then attaching the Attendee.

The frustrating part is that the registration form logic in my controller works *perfectly fine*, excerpt below. The walkthrough is that the registration controller stores each screen's data (view models) in the session using a static WorkflowManager class which handles persistence between screens. After user confirmation the controller pulls each screen's details from the WorkflowManager, runs them through AutoMapper to convert them to the relevant populated DAL entities, attaches those entities to the attendee entity, and saves it all to the database.

Again, this works perfectly fine, saving the attendee and its two child entities without error. Here is the relevant excerpt of the controller action:

```
var attendeeRegistration = WorkflowManager.GetAttendeeRegistration();
var travelRegistration = WorkflowManager.GetTravelRegistration();

using (var db = new MyContext())
{
    var attendee = Mapper.Map<Attendee>(attendeeRegistration);

    attendee.AnotherChildEntity = db.ChildEntities.Find(attendeeRegistration.SelectedChildEntityId);

    var travel = Mapper.Map<TravelSchedule>(travelRegistration);
    travel.ArrivalMode = db.TravelModes.Find(travelRegistration.SelectedArrivalModeId);
    travel.DepartureMode = db.TravelModes.Find(travelRegistration.SelectedDepartureModeId);

    var lodging = Mapper.Map<LodgingArrangement>(lodgingRegistration);
    lodging.LodgingLocation = db.LodgingLocations.Find(lodgingRegistration.SelectedLodgingLocationId);

    attendee.Comments = comments;

    attendee.TravelSchedule = travel;
    attendee.LodgingArrangement = lodging;

    db.Attendees.Add(attendee);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works perfectly. None of these objects are in the database until after the user confirms the registration is complete. So I don't understand why I can persist new entities to the database here, yet I can't do what appears to me to be the same thing in the Seed method above.

Any help or ideas much appreciated. This has been causing me endless grief for days now. Thanks.

Comment: EF doesn't use `TravelSchedule.AttendeeId` as foreign key, but `TravelSchedule.Id` (it's primary key *and* foreign key, that's how EF implements 1:1 associations).

Comment: Ok I was suspecting the problem was happening in how they were tied together. So I should just remove `AttendeeId` from the child entities and it should work? If so, why does it work in the controller but not in the seed method? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'd expect `AttendeeId` to be 0 (making it effectively useless), but the entities should be tied together in the Seed method too. You seem to have looked at `AttendeeId` only, which led you to the conclusion it didn't work, but I think that the Seed method works correctly. You should see `TravelSchedule`s having the same Id values as their `Attendee`s.

Comment: Holy cow you are right, I didn't even notice that. `TravelSchedule.Id` is identical to `Attendee.Id`. So how do I make this right? In the first instance of my loop above it looks to me like EF should automatically tie them together. Do I just need to remove `AttendeeId` from `TravelSchedule`? (but that begs the question again, why does it work in the controller but not in the seed?)

Comment: Yes, the first version should work and the mappings of the 1:n associations are correct (oh and `TravelScheduleId` is redundant too). So you can't retrieve Attendees with their TravelSchedules connected after the Seed method?

Comment: It works! Removing the extraneous *Ids did the trick. I can't believe I was staring at this problem so long I was blinded to something so simple as EF combining the keys! I fiddled with EF several years ago but its been quite a while since I did any real .NET work, I can't believe I overlooked that concept in my (admittedly increasingly panicked) readings trying to solve the problem before now. Thank you very much for your help. If you make an answer I'll accept it so you get some credit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association between `Attendee` and `TravelSchedule` is 1:1. EF implements 1:1 associations by creating a primary key in the *dependent* entity (here: `TravelSchedule`) that's also a foreign key to its *principal* entity (`Attendee`).

So `Attendee.TravelScheduleId` and `TravelSchedule.AttendeeId` are not used for the association and their values remain 0. Which means: the `Seed` works without these fields/properties (and I'd even expect it to work *with* them), it establishes the associations through the `Id` fields.

Comment: This was exactly right, I misunderstood how it worked and assumed an error existed (TravelSchedules.AttendeeId = 0) where it didn't, at least not in this iteration of my code. Thanks for the help.